Next.js build error: No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider to set one
I was building a simple 2-3 pages next.js. It's working fine on the dev mode next dev but continuously erroring in build.
I already tried to use @tanstack/react-query as per SO #65590195
The project is available on Stackblitz, if anyone can take a look to suggest a fix.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/sb1-qmet1r
next build

Error -
Error: No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider to set one

> Export encountered errors on following paths:
        /GridView
        /TableView


Github link - https://github.com/Agenty/scrapingsandbox

import issue may be import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from '@tanstack/react-query';

Doesn't work, same error
